# Add logged in user ID to foreign key field automatically in KeystoneJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, keystonejs, keystonejs6

I'm creating an application in KeystoneJS with the documentation provided for that framework. So, in my application, there are 2 tables, one is **user** and the other one is **post**. So, I would like to know, when I'm creating a post by logging into the admin area, there is a field with the foreign key column and that field is empty to fill the foreign key values coming from the user table. So, I want the system to add foreign key value to **author** automatically when I'm creating a new post with the id of logged in user in KeystoneJS.

So, I looked for everywhere to find a solution for this and I failed to find a proper solution for this.

**If anyone have any idea about this, please reply this question and it would be appreciate a lot.**

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [moderated blog example](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/usecase-blog-moderated)?

It has lists similar to your project: `Posts` and `Users`, that can be `Contributors` or `Moderators`.  The contributor/moderator distinction doesn't matter much in your case, the part you'll be interested in are the hooks on the `Post` list, specifically the [`resolveInput.create` hook](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/main/examples/usecase-blog-moderated/schema.ts#L166), which looks like this:

```
hooks: {
  resolveInput: {
    create: ({ context, resolvedData }) => {
      resolvedData.createdAt = new Date();
      if (context.session?.contributor) {
        return {
          ...resolvedData,
          createdBy: {
            connect: {
              id: context.session?.contributor?.id,
            },
          },
        };
      }
      return resolvedData;
    },
  },
  // Other hooks...
},
```

As per [the docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/hooks#resolve-input):

> The `resolveInput` function is used to modify or augment the data values passed in to a `create` or `update` operation.

So this is our chance to change values before they're saved, including populating or enforcing values like your `Post.author` field.

`resolveInput` gets the [`context` object](https://keystonejs.com/docs/context/overview), which includes a reference to the `session` object. The contents of this object is determine by your [session store functions](https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/session#session-stores) but usually contains info about the current user. In this example, if the user signed in is a contributor, we get their contributor Id from `context.session?.contributor?.id` and save it to the `createdBy` field. The `createdAt` field is also set to the current date and time.

Note that, because this hook is configured at the list level, data for the whole item should be returned (basically, the `resolvedData` object with any additional changes the hook wants to make). Another way to do this would be to add `resolvedData` functions at the field level but then we'd need two separate functions - one for `createdAt` and another for `createdBy` – each of which would return a single value. See the [hooks guide](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/hooks) for more on this distinction.

Also, its important not to conflate hooks with [access control](https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/access-control) – ie. whether a contributor should be allowed to create a post in the first place. In this example access control is configured separately, up in the list `access` config, as it should be.

One final note – at the time of writing the [hook API docs](https://keystonejs.com/docs/config/hooks) cover the `resolveInput` hook (at the list and field levels), but don't break it down into the different operations (ie. `resolveInput.create` and `resolveInput.update`). This is just a recent syntactic improvement, it doesn't change anything fundamental about how hooks are to be used. If using just the documented API, the code above could be written as:

```
hooks: {
  resolveInput: ({ operation, context, resolvedData }) => {
    // Only run for create operations (so ignore updates)
    if (operation !== 'create') return resolvedData;
    resolvedData.createdAt = new Date();
    if (context.session?.contributor) {
      return {
        ...resolvedData,
        createdBy: {
          connect: {
            id: context.session?.contributor?.id,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    return resolvedData;
  },
  // Other hooks...
},
```

Comment: brother, while I'm reading the documentation, I didn't look through the hooks as a beginner to KeystoneJS. However, once I refer your answer and then I went through the hooks documentation and could understand that's the only way to pass the logged in user id to the author's field in the post list in KeystoneJS.

Thank you so much for your assistance and appreciate it a lot